# Pandas dataframe - move N number of rows from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a training set and test set for machine learning, however the training set contains too many rows of data and the test set contains too little.  I calculated I need to move 245 rows from the training set to the test set to produce a better split.  How can I do this?  I have 5116 total rows in training set.

First I randomized the rows of the training set using this

```
train_df = train_df.sample(n = len(train_df)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

And then I wanted to grab the last 245 rows and move them to `test_df`

I found these two solutions here

[Pandas dataframe - move rows from one dataframe to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727018/pandas-dataframe-move-rows-from-one-dataframe-to-another)

and

[Pandas move rows from 1 DF to another DF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142959/pandas-move-rows-from-1-df-to-another-df)

However they are selecting the rows based on a condition which I don't have. I kind of want to do it like you would in python using slice on arrays if that's possible.

Maybe like (rows 0-5116 - 245 and all columns starting from 0)

```
transferdata_df = train_df.iloc[5115 - 245:, 0:]
```

Then append that to the test set like

```
test_df.append(transferdata_df)
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do

```
transferdata_df = train_df.iloc[- 245:, 0:]

test_df = test_df.append(transferdata_df)

train_df =train_df.drop(transferdata_df.index)
```

Comment: thanks, its working, also added `test_df = test_df.reset_index(drop=True)` at the end to reset the index in test dataframe.

Comment: @erotavlas yw :-) happy  holiday